# Where are those Pipeline Name Variables stored and how are they called?

Tags: azure-devops

(If anybody thinks of a better title, feel free to change)

In my CI Pipeline `yml` i did not add a name attribute, but there is some kind of magic in the names. I did not make the project from scratch, though chances are big that somebody else initiliaze the naming conventions. i checked branch policies and project settings and i can neither find the number nor the alpha

[image]

anybody know where to look?

Comment: Are your pipelines running GitVersion? It looks like they are. GitVersion handles setting the name of the pipeline to match the generated semver.

Comment: Yes they do! Make it an answer and i will accept. Still the question arises where does GitVersion take those variables from and how to configure it, but i will ask google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pipelines appear to be running GitVersion. GitVersion makes use of tags to determine the current version, then increments the version accordingly depending upon which branch you're building, based on YAML-defined rules.

It has an option to update the build name to match the semantic version, which it's apparently doing in this case.